# color specific cell using kableExtra and cell_spec

Tags: r-markdown, kableextra

I'm preparing a PDF file using RMarkdown and I want to color a specific cell in red using `kableExtra` and `cell_spec`. I am able to color whole row (`row_spec`) or column (`column_spec`) but I was not able to do it with `cell_spec`.
Here is the code I used to color the first row:

```
knitr::kable((mtcars), booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(1, bold = FALSE, color = "red")
```

Is it possible to color a single cell (`mtcars[1,1]`) to red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cell_spec` as follows to set cell(1,1) to red

```
cs_dt = mtcars  
cs_dt[1,1] = cell_spec(cs_dt[1,1], color = "red")

kbl(cs_dt, booktabs = T, escape = F)
```

Comment: Thank you! So it is not possible to use `cell_spec` to change the value of only one cell, right? Assume that the other cells within the same row are conditionally formatted or in different colors. In that particular case, it'd be easy to change the value of only one cell without `row_spec` command.

Comment: Never mind my earlier answer. You can easily set the color of one cell using `cell_spec`. See my edited answer. Sorry for my earlier inaccurate answers.